# How to undo a down-vote in Amazon Music?

Tags: amazon, amazon-music

I slipped and clicked thumbs-down instead of up -- how do I undo it?

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer before I realised for myself:

If the "thumbs down" is related to a specific song, if you remember which song it was, then play it again and click the "down thumb" again to undo.

In the future, if you hit "thumbs down" accidentally and it moved onto a new song, just hit the back (previous track) button. This happened to me during a play list so I didn't even know what song is was.